# get between '(..)' as id for each checked checkbox / re-check each time a checkbox checked (kendo-ui)

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

*I am working with the treacherous kendo-ui which makes adding selectors a nightmare; anyway* I am trying to simply **on click of an input checkbox element simply get the inner contents of the id selector, i need to get in between `(` and `)`. in between the parenthesis.**

The checkboxes with kendo ui are nested within `<li>` tags, and dont seem to be changed to `.checked` when checked, I have noticed the li's `aria-checked` does change to '`true`' when checked, so I am trying to use that as a handle.

I successfully add the event listener on parent `li` tags below:

```
        let chkst = document.querySelector('#shake-tree li.k-item');
        if (chkst) {
          chkst.addEventListener("click", filterByID);
        } else {
          getCur();
        }
```

within my `filterByID` function I try to search for the checked state and get the id contents and regex to inner parenthesis. the below just console logs as nothing, so either it's not detected `aria-checked` correctly or pseudo selector not working.

```
   ....
   let idChkBoxes = document.querySelectorAll(`#shake-tree li.k-item`);
    idChkBoxes.forEach(function (node) { 
      console.log(node); <---- this consoles as the below html screenshot, same
      if (node.getAttribute("aria-checked") === true) {
          let s = $(node + ">" + "input[type='checkbox']");
          let sID = s.getAttribute("id");
          console.log(s);
          let idStr = sID.split(/[()]/);
          sqlExp += "'" + idStr + "' ";          
      }
    });
    ........
```

also tried this:

```
 if ($(node).attr('aria-checked') === "true"){
              console.log(node);
 ........
```

Here is a screenshot of the mark-up:

[image]

As you can see in the mark-up above ^ the id i need is also within the inner text of a `span.k-in` element, so could grab there as well if needed, but seems more difficult to access.

---

**My goal is to get the in between `(`..`)` parenthesis `id` for each checked checkbox and re-check each time a checkbox is checked.**

Comment: Are you using the Kendo treeview with checkboxes here?

Comment: Yes kendo treeview checkboxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
    // Other initialization properties...
    check: onCheck
});

function onCheck(e) {
    let nodeText = $(e.node).text();
      
    console.log(nodeText.match(/\((.+)\)/)[1]);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/checkboxes">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.2.617/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.2.617/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.2.617/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    
    

</head>
<body>
<div id="example">

    <div class="demo-section k-content">
        <div id="treeview"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
            checkboxes: {
                checkChildren: true
            },

            check: onCheck,

            dataSource: [{
                id: 1, text: "My Documents", expanded: true, spriteCssClass: "rootfolder", items: [
                    {
                        id: 2, text: "Kendo UI Project", expanded: true, spriteCssClass: "folder", items: [
                            { id: 3, text: "about.html (123)", spriteCssClass: "html" },
                            { id: 4, text: "index.html (123)", spriteCssClass: "html" },
                            { id: 5, text: "logo.png (123)", spriteCssClass: "image" }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        id: 6, text: "New Web Site", expanded: true, spriteCssClass: "folder", items: [
                            { id: 7, text: "mockup.jpg (123)", spriteCssClass: "image" },
                            { id: 8, text: "Research.pdf (123)", spriteCssClass: "pdf" },
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        id: 9, text: "Reports", expanded: true, spriteCssClass: "folder", items: [
                            { id: 10, text: "February.pdf (123)", spriteCssClass: "pdf" },
                            { id: 11, text: "March.pdf (123)", spriteCssClass: "pdf" },
                            { id: 12, text: "April.pdf (123)", spriteCssClass: "pdf" }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }]
        });

        // show checked node IDs on datasource change
        function onCheck(e) {
          let nodeText = $(e.node).text();
          
          console.log(nodeText.match(/\((.+)\)/)[1]);
        }
    </script>

    <style>
        #treeview .k-sprite {
            background-image: url("../content/web/treeview/coloricons-sprite.png");
        }

        .rootfolder { background-position: 0 0; }
        .folder     { background-position: 0 -16px; }
        .pdf        { background-position: 0 -32px; }
        .html       { background-position: 0 -48px; }
        .image      { background-position: 0 -64px; }
    </style>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

[Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/ajuXOWIz)

Comment: @docholiday I think it is more simple than you're trying.

Comment: so the problem with this I am querying all the checked checbox ids at once, not one at a time, hence my loop above in attempt to check all checked checkboxes when a click occurs. This worked when the checkboxes weren't kendo. Now stuck on kendo, Is there a way to get all boxes which are checked with kendo?

Comment: @docholiday the point in my anwser is that you can use `.text()` and regex to get what you want. No matter how you got the checkboxes. I mean, you can loop through all of them with a jquery selector, then inside a loop, use the code i provided to each one. If you could create a full dojo of your current problem will also help to continue this issue.